# Implement verhoeff algorithm on textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to implement verhoeff algorithm for 12 digits on a text box in my html page. I found this code for 10 digits on the internet. Please tell me how to implement it and change it for 12 digits.

```
          String.prototype.verhoeffCheck = (function()
        {
    var d = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            [1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9,5],
            [2,3,4,0,1,7,8,9,5,6],
            [3,4,0,1,2,8,9,5,6,7],
            [4,0,1,2,3,9,5,6,7,8],
            [5,9,8,7,6,0,4,3,2,1],
            [6,5,9,8,7,1,0,4,3,2],
            [7,6,5,9,8,2,1,0,4,3],
            [8,7,6,5,9,3,2,1,0,4],
            [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]];
    var p = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
            [1,5,7,6,2,8,3,0,9,4],
            [5,8,0,3,7,9,6,1,4,2],
            [8,9,1,6,0,4,3,5,2,7],
            [9,4,5,3,1,2,6,8,7,0],
            [4,2,8,6,5,7,3,9,0,1],
            [2,7,9,3,8,0,6,4,1,5],
            [7,0,4,6,9,1,3,2,5,8]];
    var j = [0,4,3,2,1,5,6,7,8,9];

    return function()
    {
        var c = 0;
        this.replace(/\D+/g,"").split("").reverse().join("").replace(/[\d]/g, function(u, i, o){
            c = d[c][p[i&7][parseInt(u,10)]];
        });
        return (c === 0);
    };
})();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint: try to find the table for the dihedral group $D_6$

Comment: yes i tried to wrap this code in a function, and call that function from textbox "onKeyUp" event. but that dint work.

Comment: Well try getting the 10 digit version to work before even trying the 12 digit version

Comment: There are only 10 digits 0-9. These same tables work for any length string of digits. Read the javascript. It doesn't care how long the string and splits out each digit to work on in the function.